# Python 8puzzle '__getitem__' error

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to create an 8puzzle solver for my term project.
 When I try to run my code, I get an error :

> File "8puzzle.py", line 234, in 
>      print best_first_search(initial_state)
>    File "8puzzle.py", line 199, in best_first_search
>      explored_set = matrix_generator(m_1D)
>    File "8puzzle.py", line 181, in matrix_generator
>      m_1D = convert_to_1D(matrix)
>    File "8puzzle.py", line 11, in convert_to_1D
>      matrix_1D.append(matrix_2D[row][col])
>   TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I couldn't understand the problem.

So here is my code:

```
 import math,sys

goal_state = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,0]]   
initial_state = [[1,0,3],[4,2,5],[7,8,6]]   
initial_state_2 = [[0,2,3],[1,4,6],[7,8,5]]   

def convert_to_1D(matrix_2D):   
    matrix_1D = list()   
    for row in range(len(matrix_2D)):   
        for col in range(len(matrix_2D)):   
            matrix_1D.append(matrix_2D[row][col])   
    return matrix_1D   

def swap_blank_tile(matrix,next_pos):   
    pos=find_row_col(matrix,0)    
    blank_tile=find_row_col(matrix,0)   
    next_tile=find_row_col(matrix,next_pos)   
    set_row_col(matrix,pos,next_tile)    
    set_row_col(matrix,next_pos,blank_tile)   
    return matrix   

def hammingDistance(matrix):   
    array1=convert_to_1D(matrix)   
    arrayGoalState=convert_to_1D(goal_state)   
    tmp=0   
    i=0

    while(i<9):
        if((array1[i]!=arrayGoalState[i]) & (array1[i]!=0)):
            tmp=tmp+1
        i=i+1    
    return tmp


def manhattanDistance(matrix):   
    i=1    
    tmp=0    
    distinction=0

    while(i<9):
        row,col=find_row_col(matrix,i)
        row2,col2=find_row_col(goal_state,i)
        tmp=row+col
        tmp2=row2+col2
        distinction+=(math.fabs(tmp-tmp2))
        i=i+1
    return distinction


def swap(matrix, i, j):   
    matrix[i[0],i[1]], matrix[j[0],[1]] = matrix[j[0],j[1]], matrix[i[0],i[1]]    
    return matrix


def matrix_generator(matrix):    
    m_1D = convert_to_1D(matrix)    
    x = possible_moves(matrix)    
    list_of_states = []

    for i in x:
        new_current = []
        old_value = m_1D[i]
        new_current += swap(m_1D, m_1D.index(0), i)
        list_of_states.append(new_current)
        zero_index = m_1D.index(0)
        swap(matrix, m_1D.index(old_value), zero_index)
    return list_of_states


def best_first_search(matrix):   
    m_1D = convert_to_1D(matrix)   
    print m_1D  
    temp_solution = [m_1D]   
    explored_set = matrix_generator(m_1D)   
    step = 0   
    while goal_state:   
        step += 1

        for i in explored_set:
            explored_set += matrix_generator(i)
            x = hammingDistance(explored_set).pop()

            if x == goal_state:
                print "\nSolved in {} step(s)\n".format(step)
                return x

            elif x not in temp_solution:
                temp_solution += [x]
                explored_set = matrix_generator(x)
            else:
                explored_set.pop(explored_set.index(x))

            print x

print best_first_search(initial_state)
```

Comment: It's a lot more helpful if you can narrow down where the problem seems to be from instead of posting the entire code. At the very least there should've been a line number given with that error.

Comment: Paste only relevant code and define the line which is causing the error.

Comment: I have updated post, adding the error lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code, this is the error that occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solver.py", line 208, in <module>
    print best_first_search(initial_state)
  File "solver.py", line 187, in best_first_search
    explored_set = matrix_generator(m_1D)
  File "solver.py", line 169, in matrix_generator
    m_1D = convert_to_1D(matrix)
  File "solver.py", line 11, in convert_to_1D
    matrix_1D.append(matrix_2D[row][col])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

In the last line, this means that `matrix_2D[row]` is evaluating to an `int`, when the code is expecting a `list`. Hence the error, because an `int` does not have elements that you can access by index!

Your function `matrix_generator` is expecting a 2D matrix, but in line 187, you're passing it a 1D matrix. So replace `m_1D` with `matrix` and continue debugging from there (your code as it is raises a different error once this one has been fixed).

I would strongly suggest that you test each function first and make sure that they work as expected, and then be more careful about the data that you pass into each function.

EDIT: The line number might differ, but I believe you can find the corresponding line :)